# KeyError: '\n border' in adding variable in an HTML

Tags: python, html, email, html-email

A simple table that I want to include in an HTML email that sending by Python.

```
html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;}
th, td {padding: 5px;}
th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Basic HTML Table</h2>

<table style="width:10%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
"""
```

It works fine, then I want to insert a variable into, so change it to:

```
code = "Somebody"
html = """

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;}
th, td {padding: 5px;}
th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Basic HTML Table</h2>

<table style="width:10%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{code}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
""".format(code=code)
```

It warns:

```
    """.format(code=code)
KeyError: '\n  border'
```

I was thinking to add html = html.readline.rstrip("\n") but the error happens even before that.

How can I have it corrected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Tal said you need {} inside {}

For example : {{}}

```
code = "Somebody"
html = """

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}}
th, td {{padding: 5px;}}
th {{text-align: left;}}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Basic HTML Table</h2>

<table style="width:10%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{code}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
""".format(code=code)


print(html)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have a style block in there, and it is using the `{}` which are searched and evaluated by the `.format()` function.
Try removing it from the html by exporting it to a separated file.